# executing rsh command in perl script

Tags: perl

I want to rsh to a machine and execute some commands in a perl scriprt, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$command="cd /remote/XXX; mkdir aa";
$result=system("rsh machine $command");
```

The directory aa was not created. Can someone help me have a look? Thanks!

Comment: `/remote/XXX` is present in the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

Perl interpolates variables in double quotes. Therefore, the command was interpreted as

```
rsh machine cd /remote/XXX; mkdir aa
```

The `aa` directory was probably created on the local machine. Add single quotes so that the local shell does not interpret the semicolon:

```
$result = system("rsh machine '$command'");
```